# Make maven generate dependencies even with errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

This feels like a really stupid question but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm working on a maven project but I do most of my development in eclipse. Is there any way for me to force maven to generate all of my dependencies under target even if there are errors in the code? I set my eclipse project's build path to use the jars under target/dependencies/jars, but calling mvn clean kills them and if there are any errors in my code causing it to not compile mvn package won't create the dependencies but will instead just crash saying BUILD FAILURE. This makes the problem even worse since instead of seeing the actual errors my eclipse will just bombard me with errors everywhere since all of its dependencies just died.

Or maybe the way I'm working with it is just stupid and there's a better way.

Comment: what do yo mean generate your dependencies? compile them?
how can it compile them if there are errors in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the m2e plugins for Eclipse to process maven projects, or simply importing the projects as general ones?

If the latter, you should use the m2 plugins (simply go to the Eclipse Marketplace and search for Maven), as they interrogate your POM and set up your dependences properly. You can then concentrate on any compile errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not point to the jars in the target folder for dependent JAR's since this is where the **products of building your project** are stored. Performing a *mvn clean* removes this folder.

To use Maven with Eclipse install the m2e plugin in Eclipse. This makes Eclipse understand the structure of Maven projects.

Once installed you can import your Maven project into Eclipse. I use *Import...* | *Existing Maven Projects* for this. But you can also directly import form a versioning system.

During the import Eclipse will set up the Eclipse project to use the Maven dependencies to locate the required JAR's. These are taken from the repository as configured with the used Maven installation.